# For-looping issue VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, type-mismatch

I am having trouble with the following line of code.

```
'payFreq is input of type "Long"
Dim DF As Variant
'discFact here is input of type "Range"
DF = discFact.Value

Dim Payment_pay() As Double
ReDim Payment_pay(1 To UBound(DF))

Dim i As Long
'Fill with zeros
For i = 1 To UBound(Payment_pay)
 Payment_pay(i) = 0
Next i

Dim Prev_date As Date
Dim Next_date As Date

For i = 1 To UBound(Payment_pay)
 Prev_date = makeDate((i - payFreq_pay) & "M")
 Next_date = makeDate(i & "M")
Next i

'Continuation of code...
```

The makeDate function is basically

```
Function makeDate(Term As String) As Date
 ...
End Function
```

Trying to output the variable Prev_date or Next_date won't work! However, interchanging the upper loop bound ( UBound(Payment_pay ) to e.g. 6, will give the expected return value (a correct date...). It seems something is wrong with the looping iterator "i".

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Niklas

Comment: What is **payFreq_pay** ? .. better you show func mkdate

Comment: sorry, forgot that one. Edited now. **payFreq_pay** is of type Long (input to function). Moreover the **makeDate** function works fine when calling it with e.g. **makeDate(3 & "M")**, and then returns the current date + 3 months

Comment: **Term As String** .. "M" is string .. but **3** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
For i = 1 To UBound(Payment_pay)
 Prev_date = makeDate(format(i - payFreq_pay) & "M")
 Next_date = makeDate(format(i) & "M")
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a clock. What is the issue here? Is it because the concatenation between "i - payFreq_pay" and "M" doesn't do what I want it to do or? How come the call **makeDate(3&"M")** works then? Does VBA automatically convert the 3 into "3"?

Comment: Merciful VBA I guess .. bravoo !